# Annotations in CoffeeScript / JS

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, annotations

I looking for a way to use annotations in CoffeeScript in the following manner:

```
@requiresNetworkAccess
login = () ->
 $http
   method: 'HEAD'
   url   : endpoint
 .then (res) ->
   return
 , (err) ->
   return
```

Then in the following file `annotations.coffee` we define all annotations:

```
requiresNetworkAccess = (NetworkService) ->
  if NetworkService.isOffline
    alert "Device offline!"
    return
```

The next thing would then be to find a way to inject annotation code into annotated functions, probably by using a gulp/grunt preprocessing step.

Throwing this out there in case anyone has any thoughts on how best to do something like this, or even better if there's an existing way of getting this to work.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried [coffee-annotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coffee-annotate)?

Comment: Took a look at it. Doesn't really function the way I'd like. Besides it looks all but abandoned. 1 contributor, Haven't been updated in a year+